# I want to use UDPBasicApp in Veins based on Omnet but I can not implement

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to implement the `UDPBASICBurst` app in Veins, but I am facing problems. I have done as follows but I don't know if I am correct. Can anybody put light on this matter?

```
import inet.applications.udpapp.UDPBasicBurst;
import org.car2x.veins.base.modules.*;
import org.car2x.veins.modules.nic.Nic80211p;
```

....

```
    udpBasicBurst: UDPBasicBurst {
        @display("p=130,56");
    }`enter code here`
connections allowunconnected:
    nic.upperLayerOut --> appl.lowerLayerIn;
    nic.upperLayerIn <-- appl.lowerLayerOut;
    nic.upperControlOut --> appl.lowerControlIn;
    nic.upperControlIn <-- appl.lowerControlOut;

    veinsradioIn --> nic.radioIn;


    udpBasicBurst.udpOut --> nic.upperControlIn;
    udpBasicBurst.udpIn <-- nic.upperControlOut;
}

import inet.applications.udpapp.UDPBasicBurst;
import org.car2x.veins.base.modules.*;
import org.car2x.veins.modules.nic.Nic80211p;

module Car
{
    parameters:
        string applType; //type of the application layer
        string nicType = default("Nic80211p"); // type of network interface card
        string veinsmobilityType; //type of the mobility module
    gates:
    input veinsradioIn; // gate for sendDirect
submodules:
    appl: <applType> like org.car2x.veins.base.modules.IBaseApplLayer {
        parameters:
            @display("p=60,50");
    }

    nic: <nicType> like org.car2x.veins.modules.nic.INic80211p {
        parameters:
            @display("p=60,166");
    }

    veinsmobility: <veinsmobilityType> like org.car2x.veins.base.modules.IMobility {
        parameters:
            @display("p=130,172;i=block/cogwheel");
    }

    udpBasicBurst: UDPBasicBurst {
        @display("p=130,56");
    }
connections allowunconnected:
    nic.upperLayerOut --> appl.lowerLayerIn;
    nic.upperLayerIn <-- appl.lowerLayerOut;
    nic.upperControlOut --> appl.lowerControlIn;
    nic.upperControlIn <-- appl.lowerControlOut;

    veinsradioIn --> nic.radioIn;


    udpBasicBurst.udpOut --> nic.upperControlIn;
    udpBasicBurst.udpIn <-- nic.upperControlOut;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are importing both `inet.applications.udpapp.UDPBasicBurst` and `org.car2x.veins.modules.nic.Nic80211p` in the same module. This will likely not work the way you hope:

Simply speaking, modules in the `inet.*` namespace only expect to exchange messages with other modules from this namespace. Up to and including Veins 4a2, the same goes for modules in the `org.car2x.veins.*` namespace - with one notable exception: The Veins 4a2 `TraCIScenarioManager` will check if an instantiated module uses an inet 2.3.0 `TraCIMobility` module as their mobility submodule. If it does, it will move the module accordingly.

This allows you to use Veins 4a2 mobility in INET 2.3.0 hosts.

Comment: Dear Christoph;  I reinstalled  Veins 4a2 mobility in INET 2.3.0 hosts with respective version of SUMO and Omnet4.6.  I used the UDP and network layer module now in between app and nic module..: It runs for sometime but when it try to send UDP message then there is an error:  <!> Error in module (UDP) EScenario.node[0].udp (id=9) at event #369, t=35.704289728099: check_and_cast(): cannot cast NULL pointer to type 'UDPSendCommand *'.
  How to solve this...